# Easy way to place text inline with images

Tags: html, css

I've got the following "key" which is a div containing pictures of the planets and their names for an educational animation. Is there a quick way/shortcut (without wrapping the text in separate spans or something then assigning top/bottom/left/right properties to specific ids) to make the text appear in-line with the icons?

```
<p id='key'>
<img class='img-key' src='media/mercury.ico'> Mercury
    <br/>
<img class='img-key' src='media/venus.ico'> Venus
    <br/>
<img class='img-key' src='media/planet-earth.ico'> Earth
    <br/>
```

Comment: img {display:inline-block;}

Comment: Put here your css for #key and .img-key

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand but here are two possible solutions. If you want everything on one line, remove the `<br />` tags.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HC8kK/)**

If you want the text centered vertically with each image, set the vertical-align property to middle on the images:

```
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wL5t8/1/)**

Comment: the break tags are to have each icon and its corresponding label on their own line